# SQL server express edition a pre-requisite for using a SQL Database

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I have created a windows form application which uses an SQL database. The database will be copied by the setup onto the end user's computer. But is it necessary that the end computer should have SQL server express edition installed or just installing the .NET Framework would do?

Need this info for creating the setup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an ".mdf" database file, you need to have SQL Server installed. Either using an Express Edition (and attaching it as a user instance), or one of the more uplevel editions (e.g. Standard, Enterprise).

If you want to avoid an installation, you might be able to use SQL Server Compact, (creates ".sdf" files), which can just be bin deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing a SQL Server database onto the users machine then they will need to have an edition of SQL Server running on their machine. If your database contains only things that are in the SQL Server Express edition then that will be sufficient. If not, then they will need the appropriate edition installed on their machine.

Incidentally, if these are stand-alone applications installed onto end user's machines then you may want to look at [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) instead as that may fit your needs better. (SQL Server is designed for multi-user multi-machine access with the Express edition used mostly by hobbiests and in RAD scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your question was also looking for advice on how you'd go about deploying SQL Express as part of your application if the end user's computer does not have it.

This MSDN white paper walks you through various approaches.  The "ClickOnce" approach makes this a lot easier than it was in the past.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562(v=sql.90).aspx  (2005)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(v=sql.100).aspx  (2008)

(but as already stated, do give SQL CE a look as it may fit your needs better)